# Is it OK to use Fold without reducing number of dimensions?

Tags: types, functional-programming, dimensions, fold

For example, one wants to use `Fold` function to implement an `unique` (or `DeleteDuplicates`) function, which accepts 1-dimensional array and returns the same, but shorter. I am against it, but I can't find proof in any Wikipedia, why it is a bad practice.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a bad practice?

Comment: A lot of things can be implemented in terms of fold. It's an incredibly general function. By all means, use it where it fits naturally.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3afoldr) of various Haskell folds:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b

foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

you can clearly see that such a thing is perfectly legal -- just substitute in `[a]` for `b`.

And indeed, there are several examples in [core libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html) of folds used with such types.  There are even examples where the "number of dimensions" is increased using a fold.

Why are you against it?